# Error while building V8 on Mac Lion

Tags: javascript, v8

I am following these instructions to attempt to build V8 on Mac Lion:
http://code.google.com/apis/v8/build.html

I get this error:

```
    $ scons sample=shell mode=release snapshot=on
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
  File "/Users/pottmi/Tools/v8/v8-read-only/SConstruct", line 1569:
    Build()
  File "/Users/pottmi/Tools/v8/v8-read-only/SConstruct", line 1517:
    opts = GetOptions()
  File "/Users/pottmi/Tools/v8/v8-read-only/SConstruct", line 1153:
    AddOptions(SIMPLE_OPTIONS, result)
  File "/Users/pottmi/Tools/v8/v8-read-only/SConstruct", line 1137:
    default = guess(guess_env)
  File "/Users/pottmi/Tools/v8/v8-read-only/SConstruct", line 959:
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672:
    None
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202:
    None
```

Here are the versions of the software that I have installed:

```
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
Python 2.7.1
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
        script: v2.1.0.r5357[MODIFIED], 2011/09/09 21:31:03, by bdeegan on ubuntu
        engine: v2.1.0.r5357[MODIFIED], 2011/09/09 21:31:03, by bdeegan on ubuntu
        engine path: ['/usr/local/lib/scons-2.1.0/SCons']
```

The /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ path exists, but there is no subprocess.py file.

Comment: That's... _odd._ What version of OS X are you running, and did you install any Pythons beyond the one that comes with the OS? My `.../lib/python2.7/` folder has (among many other files) `subprocess.py`, `subprocess.pyc`, and `subprocess.pyo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the recommended way to build v8 is with gyp.  Please see http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP for information on building it that way.

Comment: I am accepting this based on reading the URL.  I reverted to using rhino to solve my immediate problem so I did not try to follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I have had much better luck in the last two years with using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) than with compiling things manually. Installing the v8 Javascript Engine through Homebrew is as simple as the following:

```bsh
[12:26] Bryson@Galactica  ~ :$ brew install v8
==> Installing v8 dependency: scons
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/scons/scons-2.2.0.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> /usr/bin/gzip scons-time.1
==> /usr/bin/gzip scons.1
==> /usr/bin/gzip sconsign.1
==> /usr/bin/python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.2.0 --standalone-lib --install-lib=/usr/
/usr/local/Cellar/scons/2.2.0: 393 files, 4.2M, built in 4 seconds
==> Installing v8
==> Downloading https://github.com/v8/v8/tarball/3.9.24
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> scons -j 8 arch=x64 mode=release snapshot=on library=shared visibility=default console=readline sample=shell
==> install_name_tool -change libv8.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/v8/3.9.24/lib/libv8.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/v8/3.9.2
/usr/local/Cellar/v8/3.9.24: 12 files, 5.8M, built in 55 seconds
```

Dependancies are installed, versions are checked, etc. From here, just type `v8` and you're into the shell.